# prevent translate tween from resetting - android

Tags: android, tween

I have a simple translate tween that moves an object up 200 pixels.  As soon as it's finished moving, it always bounces back to its original state and I don't want that.  I want it to stay where I moved it.

I know this is should be an obvious solution, but I can't find the method/property anywhere to make it just stop and not reset...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animation.setFillAfter(true) might be what you are looking for.